# Google Chrome recognizes my Qt app as malware

Tags: qt, google-chrome, malware

I made a little program in **Qt and C++** that helps to connect to the internet.
The app works great, but when I download the `.exe` (or the installer), **Google Chrome** recognizes it as **malware**.
Scanning the app with Microsoft Security Essentials does not return any problems.

I use Qt with *QFile, QString, QtextStream, QPointer, QWebview, QWebFrame, QWebElement, QUrl, QDesktopServices, QStringList, QEventLoop*.

Does anybody knows how to solve this problem?

Comment: Are you given any more information as to why your app is detected as malware? Could you post a screenshot please?

Comment: Here is a printscreen: http://www.botervlieg.be/public/TEMP/prtscr.png . It says "app.exe seems to be harmful". This ocures when downloading the application in Google Chrome.

Comment: @sjwarner : Could it be related to **Code Signing**? I used the exe file from the 'release' directory of my QT build. I didn't do any code signing as far as I know.

Comment: Check out this previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9512919/getting-around-chromes-malicious-file-warning, think it might help :)

Comment: @sjwarner, It's indeed the same problem! Funny thing is that I am allready using Webmaster Tools for that site. But maybe Google hasn't crawled the exe file yet, because it's not linked with the main website... Another strange thing is that it does work with other exe files (not compiled by me).

Comment: Google Chrome just seems to assume that *any* exe on the web could be malicious. There are many of these exes (and DLL's) which are perfectly safe that give this warning. Not exactly a pro for using Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Try to get in touch with Google service, maybe there, you can find answers.

Second idea is try to check your `.exe` by some antiviruses (for example, online service by Dr.Web -- http://vms.drweb.com/online/).