# Cloud Storage Download Appears to Be Malicious

Tags: google-chrome, google-cloud-storage

I uploaded a utility in the last few days to google cloud storage.

It's a zip file containing two executables and a readme file.

I tested the download and it worked fine.  I then looked into how I could see the download stats and yesterday I enabled logging.

I posted the link to a mailing list this afternoon and clicked it to verify that I had the right link and the download in chrome reports "xxx.zip appears to be malicious".

This did not happen prior to when I enabled logging, but I don't know for sure that is what caused it.

I am using a CNAME alias for the download, and I am a paying google apps customer.

The executables are not malicious in any way.  They are simple utilities for doing replacements in text files.  They do not access the network at all.

My question is "Why is my zip file being reported as malicious?"  and is there any way to remedy this situation?

Comment: I think any non-signed EXE inside of a ZIP might get marked as possibly malicious by Chrome. Are you using an http:// URL or https:// ? It might not report the error if you use HTTPS.

Comment: Looking into this a bit more, code signing is not a solution. http://productforums.google.com/d/msg/chrome/r-9JQIboUmc/mv55WydPZnkJ

An https url apparently does the trick, but you cannot use an https url with google cloud storage.  Requiring a certificate of any sort is bad form.  It offers no real protection.  I can understand running a scanner against a downloaded file, but simply reporting anything as malicious that contains an executable is unbelievable.

Comment: You can definitely use HTTPS with Google Cloud Storage. What did you try?

Comment: SSL cannot be used for CNAME requests, only via the commondatastorage.googleapis.com and sandbox.google.com urls.

Comment: I fail to understand why this topic should be closed.  It's applicable to the appropriate tags and is a concern to every software developer who wants to distribute downloadable executables.  This is overzealous  and unwarranted moderation.

Comment: Agreed this should not have been closed. I voted to reopen.

Answer (score 2):

I looked around for a solution to this problem and I found the following advice:

1) Sign your EXEs.  As it turns out, this advice is incorrect.  While it has worked for some people, there are people who report that even signed executables are reported as malicious downloads.

2) Use SSL.  SSL access is not available for google cloud storage unless you use the commondatastorage.googleapis.com or sandbox.google.com URLs.  While this does might work, it doesn't resolve my problem.

3) Use the commondatastorage.googleapis.com URL.  This works.  The same file using the commondatastorage.googleapis.com url rather than my custom CNAME record does not report that it "appears malicious".

4) Register your site with Google Webmaster Tools.  [Getting around Chrome's Malicious File Warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9512919/getting-around-chromes-malicious-file-warning)  According to this stackoverflow entry, the solution is to sign up for Google Webmaster Tools and add your site.

I have tried this one, but it has not made a change just yet.  Because this is google cloud storage and not a main site, I added an index.html page, a 404 page, and ran the gsutil commands to enable web configuration within google cloud storage.  I added the site to Webmaster Tools and additionally added it to Google Analytics.

I'll give solution 4 a few days to see if it pans out.

It seems like this is more of an issue with Google Chrome and not necessarily Google Cloud Storage.  Chrome's methods for identifying malicious files are less than desirable right now.