# Link to executable on the webpage. Chrome marks it as dangerous

Tags: html, security, google-chrome, executable

I need to input some hardware information in the text input on my web page. Of course it's not possible to get this information from javascript, so I put `GET CODE` link in the right side of the input which points to a small utility windows executable. This executable just copies hardware info to the clipboard and suggests to paste it to the input, but when I download it, chrome warns me saying the file is not commonly downloaded and can be dangerous.
What can I do about this to make the process looks as much as possible safe?

[image: Chrome warning]

Comment: Do you have a link to a working example? Does Chrome actually **prevent** you doing anything, or does it just **warn** you that the file might be unsafe? If it's just normal behaviour for .exe files I'm not sure anything can be done unfortunately.

Comment: No, it doesn't prevent me from executing it, it just warns and the whole process looks unsafe to the potential user.

Comment: It doesn't give the same warning for any setup application downloaded from internet. Probably it should be signed somehow?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/9727960/1773904 - have you tried adding your website to Google Webmasters?

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it and reply as soon as I have an answer.

Comment: I have the same problem. EXE is code signed, and website is registered with webmaster tools. Did you ever find a resolution?