# How to prevent my .exe to be recognized as malware?

Tags: winapi, exe, digital-signature, production-environment, malware

I have written a little tool a few days ago (see Github project [here](https://github.com/josephernest/EasyVolcaSample)) that works as a single `.exe` portable file. It is compiled/linked with:

```
cl mytool.c
```

I have uploaded the `.exe` on internet, but when people try to download it (direct link [here](http://josephernest.github.io/EasyVolcaSample/EasyVolcaSample.exe)), the file is seen as malware / potential threat, and thus can't be downloaded. (*Note that when disabling antivirus for 10 minutes, it is possible to download it successfully.*)

**How to compile/link my tool so that my `.exe` file is seen as potential threat?**

Comment: Most anti-virus companies have a whitelisting process for false positives.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Yes, but then I have to re-do this each time I do a new build of the `.exe`, and for each anti-virus company (Avast, Kaspersky, etc.).... Such a long process for a small freeware tool :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to get around this problem by putting a password on the zip file or rar file. The only thing is that you would then have to hand the password where the file is downloaded from so that users can get into it.

If you want some more information on this you could read this page:
[Getting around Chrome's Malicious File Warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9512919/getting-around-chromes-malicious-file-warning)

Hope this helps.