# Error on Downloading .msi File from my Website

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, https, windows-installer

I have an .msi file on my website for download, but the issue is when we downloads the file following error occurs:

**On Chrome:**

[image: Error]

**On Internet Explorer:**

[image: Error]

**After executing the file following Error Occurs:**

[image]

[image]

> Same Errors occurs on every other browser. So kindly tell me how do i fix it? Do i have to buy any certificate or license? Just Help Me :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this out

[Getting around Chrome's Malicious File Warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9512919/getting-around-chromes-malicious-file-warning)

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/r-9JQIboUmc. Multiple options specified. Try one of them.

This will surely help you.