# Remove download warning HTM?

Tags: html

In HTML, you can share downloadable files including `.exe` and `.zip`, but users get a warning before they download it saying that files on the internet can be dangerous, that'd definitely decrease the amount of downloads. How can I stop the warning with code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting around Chrome's Malicious File Warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9512919/getting-around-chromes-malicious-file-warning) obviously it depends on the browser you are using

Comment: @caramba Yeah, I'm using chrome, OK I'll see it.

Comment: @caramba Oh, so I have to sign up or something... is there a way to do it with code?